Connection is reestablished when I dockerize a FlaskApp and access by my localhost
I created a Python flask app. Everything works well, so I decided to Dockerize it.
But when I launch my app with docker and try to access to http://localhost:5000/ I get:

The connection has been reset

This is what my docker-compose and my Dockerfile look like:
docker-compose :
version: '3.8'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:8.15.2
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://elasticsearch:9200"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  flaskapp:
    container_name: flaskapp
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      elasticsearch:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge


Dockerfile :
FROM python:3.12

WORKDIR /IoT

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /IoT/

RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --deploy --ignore-pipfile

COPY . /IoT/

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python", "app.py"]

Here is my command which launches docker compose:
docker-compose up -d

Python files that matter:
# app/__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from .routes import main_blueprint
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.elasticsearch = Elasticsearch(["http://elasticsearch:9200"])
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    return app

# app.py

from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)

When I try from my Docker container with the URL: http://localhost:5000 it returns my template index.html, so it works.
So I tried to connect with the IP of my container and here's how I got it:
docker inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" flaskapp

but it still doesn't work.
Here is my docker compose logs flaskapp
* Serving Flask app 'app'
2024-10-06T13:42:40.797064320Z  * Debug mode: off
2024-10-06T13:42:40.798759487Z WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
2024-10-06T13:42:40.798818089Z  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
2024-10-06T13:42:40.798832090Z  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
2024-10-06T13:42:40.798841090Z  * Running on http://x.x.x.x:5000
2024-10-06T13:42:40.798850190Z Press CTRL+C to quit

I understand that my flask app works correctly within my Docker, but I don't understand why I can't access it via my PC through my localhost.

Can you double-check the logs of your container (docker compose logs flaskapp)?  Your symptom matches a reasonably well-known Flask problem (the dev server by default listens on only the container-private localhost interface) but it looks like you have the correct settings in your code (especially app.run(host="0.0.0.0")).

I just modified my body, I added my logs

That debug output is good (Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0) is important to see) and the Compose ports: look right too.  What sort of Docker installation are you using – plain Docker on native Linux, Docker Desktop, something more complicated?  Can you reach Elasticsearch via curl http://localhost:9200 or does it have the same problem?

I'm on Windows 11 so I use Docker Desktop.
Yes when I curl http://localhost:9200 it works. Is there a specific installation with certain params for Docker Desktop ?

Oh that's ok, I deleted all the old builds I had (I had already made a Flask app a year ago) and that solved the problem. Thanks again for your help, have a nice weekend
